# Reading the data and setting from and to a class with same class in different packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I have a service with Class SomeClass.java in pkg com.test.service1.
I have another service with class SomeClass.java in pkg com.test.service2.

```
SomeClass // Service1
{
List<Employee> empList;
}
```

```
SomeClass // Service2
{
List<Employee> empList;
}
```

I am currently working in service2 from which I will be invoking the service1 and getting the response from service1 SomeClass.
The contents of class in both the services is same But, I want to manipulate the data coming from service 1 SomeClass attributes so as not to disturb the Service1 response.
So, I am getting the response from service1 and trying to set it to the class in service2 before manipulating the data.

I tried the below code which is not working.
Importing two classes with same name anyways do not work.

```
List<com.test.service1.Employee> employees = service1.SomeClass.getEmpList();
List<com.test.service2.Employee> employeesList = employees;
```

Please help.

Comment: If I understood your needs, you should implement two different mappers and then use one of them depends on where you came from.

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to tackle this can be:

**1.** Using ObjectMapper.convertValue() / Gson.fromJson to clone object to another type using json parsers.

```
    public <T> T convertValue(Object dto, Class<T> clazz) {
        return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(dto), clazz);
    }


    private <T> T convertValue(Object dto, Class<T> clazz) {
        return objectMapper.convertValue(dto, clazz);
    }
```

**2.** Using MapStruct to generate code of mapper, and change the type without converting it to json first.

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface EmployeeMapper {
        com.test.service1.Employee toEmployee1(com.test.service2.Employee dto);
        com.test.service2.Employee toEmployee2(com.test.service1.Employee dto);
    }
```

in build.gradle

```
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final'
```

then just autowire the mapper bean and call the methods to convert the objects.

**3.** Implementing the converters manually. (not recommended)

**4.** Extracting Employee class to a third module and use it as common code, ditching the obligation of mapping objects back and forth.